# dynamic data and categories highcharts

Tags: php, json

I want to ask. How to display json as shown below using php and json encode?  name and data also dynamic.

I have search many forum but their name is fixed and not dynamic from database

series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

```
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }]
```

Comment: how do you want to display these data ?

Comment: check this link .. http://blueflame-software.com/pass-date-parameter-to-highcharts-line-chart/

Comment: something like what SUPER_USER suggest but i want the $result['name'] to be dynamic, could be more than one name. Name and data dynamic